# Extracting a string using Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following code to extract the string within double quotes using Regex.

```
String str ="\"Java\",\"programming\"";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

The output I get now is **java programming**.But from the String **str** I want the content in the second double quotes which is **programming**. Can any one tell me how to do that using Regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take your example, and change it slightly to:

```
String str ="\"Java\",\"programming\"";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
int i = 0
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("match " + ++i + ": " + matcher.group(1) + "\n");
}
```

You should find that it prints:

```
match 1: Java
match 2: programming
```

This shows that you are able to loop over all of the matches. If you only want the last match, then you have a number of options:

- Store the match in the loop, and when the loop is finished, you have the last match.
- Change the regex to ignore everything until your pattern, with something like: `Pattern.compile(".*\"([^\"]*)\"")`

If you really want explicitly the second match, then the simplest solution is something like `Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"[^\"]*\"([^\"]*)\"")`. This gives two matching groups.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the last token inside double quotes, add an end-of-line archor (`$`):

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"$");
```

In this case, you can replace `while` with `if` if your input is a single line.

Answer (score 1):

Great answer from Paul. Well,You can also try this pattern

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",\"(\\w+)\"");
```

Java program

```
     String str ="\"Java\",\"programming\"";
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",\"(\\w+)\"");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Explanation**

**`,\"`**: matches a comma, followed by a quotation mark `"`

**`(\\w+)`**: matches one or more words

**`\"`**: matches the last quotation mark  `"`

Then the group`(\\w+)` is captured (group 1 precisely)

**Output**

```
programming
```

Comment: What if I want to print **Java** and **Programming**  separate using 2 different print statement. How can I do that?

Comment: then use this pattern `final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^\",]+)");`

Comment: I want to separate **java** and **programming**  into two different strings and print it.

Comment: ok. its now i understand what you meant. Use this `final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(\\w+)\",\"(\\w+)\"");` then `System.out.print(matcher.group(1))`, `System.out.print(matcher.group(2))`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.